# Magento Resending Order email

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

I am trying to figure out the issue with receiving the BCC of orders placed. in the process, resend an older test order.

I am wondering if resending an older order triggers an email to the `Send Order Email Copy Method` and thus the emails be sent to `Send Order Email Copy To` also or do i have to place another new test order to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I test it. You can resend email from admin order page. it will  send email to custoemr as well as Copy Email.

so for test `Send Order Email Copy To` You don't need to place another order.